# How to Subscribe to change notifications to the /communications/callRecords endpoint in Graph API for my WPF Project

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, webhooks

I need to track Microsoft teams call And there is callrecords Endpoint in Microsoft Graph, I need Callchainid to get data from that endpoint. So I need to Subscribe to change notifications to the /communications/callRecords endpoint to get callchainid.

Which url to give in notificationurl? How to handle the results?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed the [public documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/changenotifications-for-callrecords) for notifications from call records?

Also, `notificationurl` should be the URL to an app set up by you that will receive the notifications when a call record has been created/modified depending on what you specified during the subscription request. This app should have the `CallRecords.Read.All` permission as you can read in the documentation.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35478348)

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine, yes the second part of my answer is answering the specific question, but I think that adding the link to the documentation is important as well. Thanks anyway for your suggestion.